# Gitlab CI/CD: Build and push only changed images in multi container app

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I'm learning CI/CD using a multi container app in a single repo. The idea is to detect changed files, build the image and push it to docker hub.

I can get the pipeline to build and push all the images when I push to master, but it never runs if I use the `changes` rule.

This is the pipeline:

```yaml
build_image:
  image: docker:20.10.16
  services:
    - docker:20.10.16-dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $DOCKERHUB_USER -p $DOCKERHUB_PASS
  script:
    - docker build -t $DOCKERHUB_USER/test:$SERVICE-$VERSION ./$SERVICE/
    - docker push $DOCKERHUB_USER/test:$SERVICE-$VERSION
  rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
    changes: 
      - ./$SERVICE/**/*
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - SERVICE:
        - app
        - db
```

Each service is a folder in the root of the project, changing any file in the folder should trigger the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time of fumbling around with this I discovered the problem was just the "./" before the changes directory.

This works as intended:

```yaml
build:
  image: docker:20.10.16
  services:
    - docker:20.10.16-dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
    # VERSION: 1.1.4
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $DOCKERHUB_USER -p $DOCKERHUB_PASS
  script:
    - ls ./$SERVICE
    - VERSION=$(grep '<version>' $SERVICE/pom.xml | sed -n '2s/[^0-9.]//gp')
    - docker build -t $DOCKERHUB_USER/test:$SERVICE-$VERSION ./$SERVICE/
    - docker push $DOCKERHUB_USER/test:$SERVICE-$VERSION
  rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
    changes: 
      - $SERVICE/**/*
  parallel:
      matrix:
        - SERVICE:
          - app
          - db
```